# Lua C Compiling -llua Error

Tags: c, gcc, lua

I am attempting to compile some C code to run with Lua through the command:

```
gcc -o first first.c -llua -lm
```

and the output I receive:

```
ld: library not found for -llua
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I have also tried:

```
-llua53
-llua5.3
```

But it still provides the same error. Would anyone be able to lead me to find out what library I need to provide with compiling, and where it's located?

Comment: `-llua` should work. Are you building Lua from scratch? Is Lua installed system-wide? Looks like you're missing an `-L path` in there.

Comment: I have lua installed in my /usr/local/ folder, what file would i use for the library? what would it be called?

Comment: And `ls /usr/local/lib/liblua.a` successfully shows a file? If so, you might have a bad setup of clang. To test, try appending `-L/usr/local/lib` to your command line.

Comment: yep it successfully shows the file exists. and just a question, what would executing `gcc -o first first.c -lm -L/usr/local/lib -llua` do? Like what effect would `-L/usr/local/lib` have?

Comment: Update: It works, I just want to know why :P

Comment: `-L` tells the compiler to look in an additional directory for `.a` (library) files when linking. For whatever reason, your installation of clang isn't looking in `/usr/local/lib` by default, which it should be doing. What platform are you on? OS/X? I'm assuming so since your `gcc` command is symlinked to `clang`.

Comment: @Qix You should fill the answer to get rid of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the name of the static library file. e.g. if it is called `liblua.a` the linker cannot find the `llua` library.

I simply renamed the file `liblua.a` to 'llua.a'.